# Every loop an unique variable

Tags: php

Is there any way I can use an unique variable for every time the code runs a `foreach` loop? Maybe there is an other way to fix this. If I have more than one project in the directory it will count both of the projects.

Everytime I use the carousel the counter will count through all of the directories. It need to be unique for every project.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$directory = "./public/img/portfolio/". $row['naam_project'] ."/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

$i = 0;

foreach($images as $image)
{
    ?>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<?php
foreach($images as $image)
{
    $i++;
    ?>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(<?php echo $i; ?>)"></span> 
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking about and what you want to achieve and what is the error with your code.

Comment: If you just want to have an unique id: **md5(uniqid(rand(), true))**

Comment: If I read this correctly,  $row['naam_project'] comes from the database (though that code is not included here). You should probably loop over your database result to output each project.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: just add `$i=0;` before every `foreach` command

Comment: What is $row['naam_project'] ?

Answer (score 0):

use foreach key value key is unique for array

{foreach($images as $key->$value)
{

```
?>
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(<?php echo $key; ?>)"></span> 
<?php
```

}}